# Is the sequence $a_n=\cos(n)/\sqrt{n+1}$ in $L_2$?

Tags: metric-spaces, lp-spaces

I have been trying to show that the  sequence $a_{n}$ belongs to $L_2$,
$$ a_{n} =\frac{ \cos(n)} {\sqrt{n+1} } $$
But none of the test of convergence that i have tried, show that the following series converges.
$$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} |a_{n} |^{2}$$

I wanted to ask for a hint for proving that the sequence does belong to $L_2$ space. Or perhaps it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\cos^2n$ as $\cos(2n)/2+1/2$; the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\cos(2n)/(n+1)$ is convergent (use Abel's transform) and the series  $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}1/(n+1)$ is divergent hence $(a_n)$ does not belong to $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work: Since $\cos(n)$ will be equidistributed in $[-1,1]$ this means that $\cos^2(n)\geq \epsilon>0$ will  hold for a positive fraction (depending on $\epsilon$)of indices $n$.

So you can lowerbound the sum by the Harmonic series.

Comment: But $\cos^2(n)$  is strictly less than 1, so does not that mean, the harmonic serie is an upper bound and not a lower bound

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08 fix $\epsilon = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}.$ Whjat happens?

Comment: I see now what you mean, since that positive fraction of values of cos^2(n) satisfies the inequality you mention, we can assure the divergence of the series by comparing with the harmonic series.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I wonder if i can use the following idea for a rigorous proof? Define a subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$ s.t the indices of the subsequence satisfy that $cos^2(n)≥ ε$, then the infinite series of the subsequence diverges, and since the infinite series of $|a_{n}|^2 $ is strictly bigger that the previous one it diverges

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08 you are right, I was being a bit imprecise